# Lua - How can I grab any return?

Tags: lua

I am interested in grabbing any return format of a function. For example

```
function foo()
  return 1
end

local result = foo() -- foo is numeric 1

function foo()
  return {1,2,3}
end
local result1, result2, result3 = foo()
local result = foo() -- this is bad as result is `1` but `2` and `3` are lost

function foo()
  return 1, 2, 3
end
local result = foo() -- foo is a table with all the numbers, that's ok
```

I am building a profiler which will overwrite functions with proxy functions but I need to know the data returned, then check `type()` of it and access accordingly` but from the code it can be seen that I am unable to access all 3 situations with one method. Is there any ?

Comment: @NicolBolas as I've given three examples of `foo()` function it should be clear that I want to grab all three cases of `foo`. Please no tangents needed here.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks for helping :) I've updated my question, I hope its more clear now

Comment: So you're the actual caller of the function. Do you intend to inspect those results, then return them as if you were `foo`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the maximum number of returns is known, use something like

```
v1,v2,v3 = foo()
```

but you won't be able to tell whether `foo` returned two values or three, with the last one being nil.

The robust solution is to collect all returns in a table:

```
v = table.pack(foo())
```

Then `v.n` contains the number of returned values, including all nils.

Comment: Note that table.pack requires Lua 5.2+

Comment: Since Lua 5.2 was released 4 years ago, this should be ok, unless you're using LuaJIT, which only supports Lua 5.1.

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but LuaJIT is kinda popular, so it's best to know up-front.

Comment: If you dont have access to `table.pack` you can try using `v = {foo()}`

Comment: LuaJIT does support `table.pack()` if built with `-DLUAJIT_ENABLE_LUA52COMPAT`

Comment: @Rochet2: No, that's not quite the same. It doesn't set the `n` field of the table, which means you can't know if there were `nil`s between return values. That's *extremely* important.

Comment: @lhf RIBLOX also uses Lua 5.1

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version that works on any Lua version 5.1+.

```
local function WrapAndInspect(Inspector, FunctionToCall)
    local function Inspect(...)
        Inspector(...)
        return ...
    end
    local function Wrapper(...)
        return Inspect(FunctionToCall(...))
    end
    return Wrapper
end
```

What `WrapAndInspect` does is generate a function that will call the given function, then pass its return values to a second function you provide. That function can do whatever processing you feel is necessary on them. But the framework will ensure that the return values from the original function are passed as they were.

Here's a variation that does something similar, but instead of wrapping the `FunctionToCall`, it returns a function that *takes* a function to be called (along with its parameters):

```
local function CallAndInspect(Inspector)
    local function Inspect(...)
        Inspector(...)
        return ...
    end
    local function Caller(FunctionToCall, ...)
        return Inspect(FunctionToCall(...))
    end
    return Caller
end
```

You could use this one on any particular function you want to inspect.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround for those that do not have access to `table.pack`.
To me it seems simple and it should work on lua 5.1 and above - and maybe even earlier lua versions.

`table_pack` should work like `table.pack`

```
function table_pack(...)
    return {n=select("#", ...), ...}
end
function foo()
    return 1, 2, 3
end

local v = table_pack(foo())
print(v.n)
```

Comment: The `...` must come last to be expanded to all arguments, so `{ n=select("#", ...), ... }` works better!

Comment: @siffiejoe I wonder if there is any real difference. I tested this code on lua 5.3.
Is there any case where it actually "works better" - as you say?

Comment: There *is* a real difference: your code only works for one argument. You can check by adding `for i = 1, v.n do print(i, v[i]) end` to your sample code above. To [quote](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9) from the Lua manual: If the last field in the list has the form exp and the expression is a function call or a vararg expression, then all values returned by this expression enter the list consecutively (see §3.4.10). `...` is not the last expression in the table constructor, so it is adjusted to one value.

Comment: And while we are at it: `...` outside of parameter lists is a syntax error in Lua 5.0, so the code does not work on earlier versions. A working version for Lua 5.0 would be: `function table_pack(...) return arg end`.