# Is it possible to figure out the return value of a function in lua? Or whether or not a function returns anything?

Tags: function, lua, return-value

Lets say for example I have made a function and it's purpose is to analyze another function supplied as a parameter and return whether or not the function specified will return anything, and if so what value it will return.

```
local function CheckFunctionReturn(func)
  --return whether func would return anything.
end
local function myFunc()
  return 123;
end
CheckFunctionReturn(myFunc);
```

I am stuck with this. Perhaps there is a function in the debug library that can help? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can get `string.dump(func)` and analyze the bytecode on number of values returned from this function (search for `RETURN A B` operation code, `B=1` means no values returned).

Comment: See also lbci – a bytecode inspector library at http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#lbci

Comment: But this seems an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)... What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I am sorry if i am being rude but could you be a bit more specific because every time i print a function from string.dump, it outputs "LuaQ".

Comment: @ihf, this is not an XY problem, I am simply trying to determine whether a function supplied through a parameter returns anything.

Comment: @mikebayko That makes it seem like it _is_ an XY problem. Why are you trying to determine that? For what purpose?

Comment: @mikebayko: Let's put it a different way. I cannot think of a reason why I would ever *need* to even ask such a question of a function. If you have no idea what a function will return, then you probably have no idea what that function will accomplish for you. And thus, you have no reason to call it, since you only call functions to get them to do something. If you want to be able to capture a function's return values regardless of how many there may be, then your question is useless (and [the answer to that is easy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34956392/734069)). So why do you need to know?

Comment: Does this help? If a function ever returns, it always returns a list of zero or more values. (Other possibilities are that it raises an error or that it never returns or the program crashes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the functions in the debug library can do this. Instead you need to analyse the source code or the bytecode to find out what the program will do. There are some resources available [on the Lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ProgramAnalysis), and others have given good suggestions above as well.

Note that the problem of whether an arbitrary function will return or not when it is given arbitrary input is the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), and was proven to be impossible to solve in the general case by Alan Turing back in 1936. However, for simple functions and/or inputs it is solvable, so if your specific case is simple enough you might be able to do it.

Comment: Simple examples: `function() if condition() then return true end end` could return 0 or 1 values depending on the test. For variadic return, e.g. `function() if condition() return 23, foo() else return bar() end` the result even depends on one or more other functions, which would need to be analyzed as well. This is further complicated & can be made impossible if (potentially) endless loops, `error` / `pcall`, coroutines, external C calls, or general external effects (result depends on the weather / result of an API call / …) are involved.

Comment: Thank you for the help I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is quick-and-dirty solution (only Lua 5.1, only LE architecture), which is likely to work in most cases, but not always.
It only answers the question "Whether or not this function would return some values?"

```
local function CheckFunctionReturn(func)
   -- returns true if func would return anything

   local d = string.dump(func)
   assert(d:sub(1,5) == "\27LuaQ") -- only Lua 5.1

   -- search for code before first "return" (0x0080001E)
   d = d:match"^.-\30%z\128%z"

   -- search for "return" with non-zero number of returned values
   for pos = #d % 4 + 1, #d, 4 do
      local b1, b2, b3, b4 = d:byte(pos, pos+3)
      local dword = b1 + 256 * (b2 + 256 * (b3 + 256 * b4))
      local OpCode, BC = dword % 64, math.floor(dword/16384)
      local B, C = math.floor(BC/512), BC % 512
      if OpCode == 30 and C == 0 and B ~= 1 then
         return true
      end
   end
   return false
end

print(CheckFunctionReturn(aFunctionToBeAnalyzed));
```

Comment: Will this work if a function does something like `return SomeOtherFunction(params)`? That is, if it uses a tail call in its return statement?

Comment: @NicolBolas - Yes, the presence of "RETURN" opcode with multiple (vararg) values is considered as "this function returns something".  For some strange reason Lua always generate "TAILCALL" paired with "RETURN VARARG".  So, there is no need for special handling of "TAILCALL" opcode.

Comment: Simply looking for return instructions is only going to distinguish between functions that always return a zero-length list from functions that might return a non-zero-length list sometimes.

Comment: @TomBlodget - Correct.  As far as I understood, OP wants to distinguish between functions which always return something from functions which always return nothing (without executing those functions).

Comment: Thank you also for help egor; I use Lua 5.1, so your solution would definitely be of help to me at least to find out if a function will return anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
local function CheckFunctionReturn(func)
    print(type(func()))
end

local function myFunc()
    return 123;
end

CheckFunctionReturn(myFunc);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: For this specific function this works fine, but I think the question was about functions in general, not just the example that was given. For example, to find out if a function returns or not, you can't just run the function, because if it doesn't return you would never get an answer. (You could assume it doesn't return if it takes more than x seconds, but it might just take a long time to execute.)

Answer (score 0):

The Lua built-in [debug API](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.9) docs says

> The return hook: is called when the interpreter returns from a function. The hook is called just before Lua leaves the function. There is no standard way to access the values to be returned by the function.